# Redirecionamento: Location vs Refresh

Tags: http, redirecionamento, header

Quando usar *Location* e *Refresh* par fazer redirecionamento.

```
    header( "Location: www.dominio.com" , TRUE , 302 )
    header( "Refresh:5; url=www.dominio.com" , TRUE , 302 )
```

Ambas opções produzem o mesmo resultado: *redirecionamento*. A diferença é que usando *Location* o redirecionamento é instantâneo, enquanto *Refresh* pode-se definir um delay para o redirecionamento.

Estou querendo compreender as diferenças entre os dois casos, quando optar por um ou outro. Já que *Refresh* possui a vantagem de escolher o tempo, não vejo sentido no *Location*.

Pode-se definir o *status 3xx* nos dois casos. O *status-code* é quem informa os casos de redirecionamento, então *Location* e *Refresh* são apenas um meio para um objetivo - são indiferentes?

Comment: Fiquei curioso agora. O refresh altera o histórico da mesma forma que o redirecionamento?

Comment: Algo relacionado está [nessa questão](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1571973), mas para falar a verdade, não compreendi bem.

Comment: Talvez [essa questão](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283752/refresh-http-header) responda sua dúvida

Comment: Acho que essa questão não é relacionada somente com [tag:php], talvez alterar a tag para [tag:http] seja mais coerente.

Comment: Valeu @gmsantos, alterei a tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As duas funções servem para redirecionar/atualizar uma página, contudo eles possuem formas distintas de funcionar.

Com o `Location` o navegador não tem que baixar todo o conteúdo da página antes de fazer o redirecionamento. Desta forma o não haverá problemas em usar o botão de voltar do seu navegador pois a função é feita server-side.

Com a função de `Refresh` você estara enviando uma solicitação para o navegador ( client-side) para que atualize a página. Ou seja, o navegador ira primeiro fazer o download da página e, em seguida o tempo setado na meta tag, ira fazer o redirecionamento da página. 
Alem disso, se o utilizador clicar em "Voltar" no navegador não ira funcionar como deveria, pois voltara para a pagina em que ele acabou  de sair e sera redirecionado novamente.

---

**Location**

- Server-side
- Não faz download do site antes de redirecionar

**Refresh**

- Client-side
- Pode definir tempo para enviar para próxima página
- Pode atrapalhar o bom funcionamento do botão voltar do navegador
- Faz o download do conteudo do sites antes de redirecionar

---

Para mais informações: http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/reback

Comment: Perfeito! Explica muito bem cada funcionalidade. Agora está mais facil decidir quando usar cada caso.

Comment: @Leandro Godoy Rosa, poderia dissertar mais sobre isso?

Comment: Conferindo melhor a resposta dele vi que eu interpretei um pouco errado, agora percebi que ele se refere ao Location como o header, enquanto ao Refresh como sendo a tag `meta` enquanto eu considerava que os dois fossem o header, já que sua pergunta foi sobre os headers e não a tag `meta`. Se tratando dos headers acho errado dizer que um é server-side e o outro cliente-side, redirecionamento com o status code 3XX é considerado server-side porém depende da implementação client-side, quem realmente abre o endereço novo é o cliente

Comment: Mas de qualquer forma acho que esta resposta não é a correta para a pergunta já que a pergunta em si foi sobre os headers Location e Refresh, e a resposta foi sobre o header Location e o uso da tag meta para fazer o refresh

Comment: Um detalhe que acho importante também e não tem em nenhuma das respostas, o header Refresh na verdade não faz parte da especificação do HTTP/1.1, se não me engano foi criado na época do Netscape e continua sendo suportado pelos navegadores. Se você conferir no [RFC7231](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.4.3) do HTTP/1.1 ele diz que um redirecionamento 302 por exemplo DEVE conter o campo Location, e o Refresh não está em lugar algum do RFC

Comment: @LeandroGodoyRosa eu sabia disso, mais não tinha fundamento para provar, elabore uma resposta com isso, é bem legal

Answer (score 2):

Para descobrir a diferença teremos que analisar essa questão de dois pontos de vista, server-side e client-side:

## Server-side

Para o servidor não tem diferença, será simplesmente mais uma resposta HTTP com  o status 302 que na especificação é status de redirecionamento. "Como assim não tem diferença ?" Isso mesmo para o servidor que importa é a requisição a resposta é de interesse do cliente(desconsiderando gateways http) então aqui percebemos que teremos que analisar esse problema do lado do cliente!

## Client-side

Agora que sabemos que o problema está aqui temos que entender uma coisa sobre o cliente HTTP: Para o cliente HTTP não importa qual status e cabeçalho o servidor mande, a resposta será sempre baixada para o cliente, a responsabilidade de mandar um body ou não está no servidor, por mais que a resposta seja de interesse do cliente ele não consegue fazer isso. Sabendo disso percebemos que a diferença não está no baixar ou não o conteúdo da resposta! 
Por essas horas você vai perguntar: "Tá, então qual a diferença?". E eu teria que responder: "Qual o seu cliente HTTP? Um browser? Um cliente JavaScript? Um cliente PHP? Como ele está implementado?". O que é feito com as cabeçalhos da resposta é de decisão do cliente HTTP! Então sem conhecer o seu cliente não tem como saber como será o comportamento para cada resposta.

## Conclusão

Percebemos que a diferença irá se manifestar na implementação do cliente HTTP, então não posso responder com precisão qual é a diferença! Mas em geral a diferença é que a header ***Refresh*** foi criada para apresentar o conteúdo da resposta antes do redirecionamento, já a header ***Location*** não apresenta nenhum conteúdo por mais que o tenha.

Comment: Mais uma ótima resposta. Só não entendi uma coisa. Refresh e Location possuem diferença entre browser e javascript, ou o caso do JS foi o um exemplo de cabeçalho de status para uma requisição assíncrona?

Comment: É que quando você realiza um AJAX por exemplo o javascript não realiza um follow redirect automático, a não ser que você implemente isso, em alguns navegadores atuais isso não é mais verdade... Então mesmo que você responda com status 302 e com a header _location_ se o seu cliente javascript não implementou o follow redirect não irá acontecer nada! Já nos browsers vai depender de cada um, cada navegador implementa do seu jeito, ainda bem que os navegadores populares seguem relativamente bem as especificações HTTP =)

Comment: Meu caso é via navegador. Obrigado pela explicação.